# Is there an easy way to convert MooTools code into JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I put a site together last year and used a MooTools object someone else wrote to provide tabbing functionality. I never took the time to learn MooTools.

Since that time, I have learned JQuery and have realized there are many more plugins available and I have decided to use it exclusively moving forward. However, I haven't learned it to the point where I can write my own plugin yet.

Long story short, I would like to convert the tabbing MooTools code to JQuery. I really don't care to learn MooTools to the point where I can do it myself because I have decided not to use it at all. I use [this tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) frequently to convert C# code to VB. Is there an equivalent for MooTools to JQuery?

If not, I am posting the code I am trying to convert to JQuery from MooTools. Here is a sample page where it is in use: http://www.foldingchairdepot.com/p/National-Public-Seating-600-Series-Blow-Molded-Resin-Plastic-Folding-Chair---Set-of-4---Gray__NPS-602.aspx.

```
/**
 * SimpleTabs - Unobtrusive Tabs with Ajax
 *
 * @example
 *
 * var tabs = new SimpleTabs($('tab-element'), {
 *   selector: 'h2.tab-tab'
 * });
 *
 * @version  1.0
 *
 * @license  MIT License
 * @author  Harald Kirschner <mail [at] digitarald.de>
 * @copyright 2007 Author
 */
var SimpleTabs = new Class({

 Implements: [Events, Options],

 /**
  * Options
  */
 options: {
  show: 0,
  selector: '.tab-tab',
  classWrapper: 'tab-wrapper',
  classMenu: 'tab-menu',
  classContainer: 'tab-container',
  onSelect: function(toggle, container, index) {
   toggle.addClass('tab-selected');
   container.setStyle('display', '');
  },
  onDeselect: function(toggle, container, index) {
   toggle.removeClass('tab-selected');
   container.setStyle('display', 'none');
  },
  onRequest: function(toggle, container, index) {
   container.addClass('tab-ajax-loading');
  },
  onComplete: function(toggle, container, index) {
   container.removeClass('tab-ajax-loading');
  },
  onFailure: function(toggle, container, index) {
   container.removeClass('tab-ajax-loading');
  },
  onAdded: Class.empty,
  getContent: null,
  ajaxOptions: {},
  cache: true
 },

 /**
  * Constructor
  *
  * @param {Element} The parent Element that holds the tab elements
  * @param {Object} Options
  */
 initialize: function(element, options) {
  this.element = $(element);
  this.setOptions(options);
  this.selected = null;
  this.build();
 },

 build: function() {
  this.tabs = [];
  this.menu = new Element('ul', {'class': this.options.classMenu});
  this.wrapper = new Element('div', {'class': this.options.classWrapper});

  this.element.getElements(this.options.selector).each(function(el) {
   var content = el.get('href') || (this.options.getContent ? this.options.getContent.call(this, el) : el.getNext());
   this.addTab(el.innerHTML, el.title || el.innerHTML, content);
  }, this);
  this.element.empty().adopt(this.menu, this.wrapper);

  if (this.tabs.length) this.select(this.options.show);
 },

 /**
  * Add a new tab at the end of the tab menu
  *
  * @param {String} inner Text
  * @param {String} Title
  * @param {Element|String} Content Element or URL for Ajax
  */
 addTab: function(text, title, content) {
  var grab = $(content);
  var container = (grab || new Element('div'))
   .setStyle('display', 'none')
   .addClass(this.options.classContainer)
   .inject(this.wrapper);
  var pos = this.tabs.length;
  var evt = (this.options.hover) ? 'mouseenter' : 'click';
  var tab = {
   container: container,
   toggle: new Element('li').grab(new Element('a', {
    href: '#',
    title: title
   }).grab(
    new Element('span', {html: text})
   )).addEvent(evt, this.onClick.bindWithEvent(this, [pos])).inject(this.menu)
  };
  if (!grab && $type(content) == 'string') tab.url = content;
  this.tabs.push(tab);
  return this.fireEvent('onAdded', [tab.toggle, tab.container, pos]);
 },

 onClick: function(evt, index) {
  this.select(index);
  return false;
 },

 /**
  * Select the tab via tab-index
  *
  * @param {Number} Tab-index
  */
 select: function(index) {
  if (this.selected === index || !this.tabs[index]) return this;
  if (this.ajax) this.ajax.cancel().removeEvents();
  var tab = this.tabs[index];
  var params = [tab.toggle, tab.container, index];
  if (this.selected !== null) {
   var current = this.tabs[this.selected];
   if (this.ajax && this.ajax.running) this.ajax.cancel();
   params.extend([current.toggle, current.container, this.selected]);
   this.fireEvent('onDeselect', [current.toggle, current.container, this.selected]);
  }
  this.fireEvent('onSelect', params);
  if (tab.url && (!tab.loaded || !this.options.cache)) {
   this.ajax = this.ajax || new Request.HTML();
   this.ajax.setOptions({
    url: tab.url,
    method: 'get',
    update: tab.container,
    onFailure: this.fireEvent.pass(['onFailure', params], this),
    onComplete: function(resp) {
     tab.loaded = true;
     this.fireEvent('onComplete', params);
    }.bind(this)
   }).setOptions(this.options.ajaxOptions);
   this.ajax.send();
   this.fireEvent('onRequest', params);
  }
  this.selected = index;
  return this;
 }

});
```

Comment: this is not a mootools question, it just so happens that the features example one is done in mootools.

Comment: also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335191/please-convert-this-to-jquery-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no "converter" that will take motools code and make it jQuery ready.

However, I would highly highly (highly) recommend using a solution like jQuery UI's tab functionality found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/. It's drop dead simple to implement and has great support with many options.

If you still decided to roll your own, there is a very straight forward tutorial (screencast) over at jQuery for designers that will teach you the basics. This is how I learned (no use in reinventing the wheel): http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/

Comment: Well, not reinventing the wheel is what this is all about. Actually, it was incorporating JQuery UI that started this all - realizing that using 2 object frameworks on a single page is overkill. I looked at the tabbing functionality and using it would require some HTML structure changes to my page not to mention it is tied to the theming which doesn't quite give me the look I want. For lack of alternative, I will probably eventually use JQuery UI but for now I don't want to have to make major changes to the page. The issue isn't learning JQuery - it is learning MooTools, which I don't care to.

Comment: Structure wise it doesn't look too far off. e.g. - An outer div, an unordered list where each anchor points to a div w/ an ID. Theming would be a few simple adjustments, all css.

Comment: @NightOwl888 There are many MANY other tabs plugins for jQuery that you can use, many of them quite simple and without many requirements. It is likely to be much easier to try to adapt your existing code to use those than to try converting Mootools code, because as you say, you don't want to learn Mootools.

Comment: yeah, learning mootools would mean learning some javascript, let's not overexert ourselves. as for your conversion question, you can use moo4q (http://www.moo4q.com) to get mootools class functionality in jquery and you can rewrite the methods via the jquery dom methods you are familiar with.

Comment: @Dimitar - I haven't tried it yet, but moo4q looks promising. In fact, the sample tabs that they show on the site must have been the starting point the author of SimpleTabs used - the code is strikingly similar. BTW - you should post this as an Answer, not a comment - if moo4q does the trick, I will definitely give you the props for answering the question.